# JBehave empty context

Tags: java, selenium, jbehave, serenity-bdd

Serenity and JBehave is used for one test suite.
I'm trying to get current story and scenario names for BrowserStack videos naming.
As I read in the [official documentation](https://jbehave.org/reference/stable/context-view.html) 
for this purposes used ContextView. I got code below from the [official repository](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/d4abd2b05ae1fd4cc73c24453421b6c8ab3f0540/examples/core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/examples/core/JFrameCoreStories.java) and changed it a little:

```
public class MyStory extends SerenityStories {

  private final CrossReference xref = new CrossReference();
  private Context context = new Context();
  private Format contextFormat = new ContextOutput(context);
  private ContextView contextView = new JFrameContextView().sized(640, 120);
  private ContextStepMonitor contextStepMonitor = new ContextStepMonitor(context, contextView, xref.getStepMonitor());

  @Override
  public Configuration configuration() {
      Configuration configuration = super.configuration();
      configuration.useStepMonitor(contextStepMonitor);
      return configuration;
  }

}
```

After executing I saw JFrame window only with current step.
But `context.getCurrentScenario();` and `context.getCurrentStory();` always null.

All that I need is get scenario name before driver call and set in in the driver capability. What am I doing wrong? Maybe there's another way to do it?

P.S. serenity-jbehave 1.13.0, serenity-core 1.2.3-rc.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an instance of [ContextStoryReporter](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/jbehave-core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/core/reporters/ContextStoryReporter.java) to your configuration:

```java
configuration.storyReporterBuilder().withReporters(new ContextStoryReporter(context));
```